# Why does .innerHTML edit the src attributes?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a chrome extension and trying to replace a certain word with another.

```
let allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*');

allElements.forEach(function (element) {
      element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.split(word).join("████");
}
```

The above code edits `src` and `srcset` attributes as well.
`element.innerText` and `element.Textcontent` removes all the CSS from the webpage.

Comment: `innerHTML` is quite literally, all of the contained HTML (tags, text, attributes etc.) You probably want to select text nodes.

Comment: Would [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) work?

Comment: I tried with .innerText, but it removed all the CSS on the webpage. Same with .textContent

Comment: @Gosho Indeed, replacing `.innerText` or `.textContent` strips all of the tags inside the modified tag, and when you select on `*`, you are selecting the `<html>` tag, which then removes the entire `<head>` tag. Unfortunately, just selecting on `<body>` is not enough either, because that too will strip any tags within it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace a word or just a string? If a word, what rules do you have for determining that it is a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunaly inner/outerHTML are changing all child elements too what causes them to be re-rendered by the browser (even if not changed). this also means you may "replace" some text multiple times if your selector received elements from all levels and the replacement text contains the original text too.

So the proper way is to change just the text-elements without touching the child-elements. This way you will not experience any of the mentioned problems:

```
let word = "yourword"

let allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*');
allElements.forEach(function (element) {
    element.childNodes.forEach(function(el){
        if (!el.nodeValue) return;
        el.nodeValue = el.nodeValue.split(word).join("████");
    });
});
```